# Orthogonality of the Hermite polynomials: probabilistic approach

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

Can anyone help me with the following question:

Is there any reference in which a probabilistic approach was used to prove that the Hermite polynomials are orthogonal?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear ltt: Are these two questions related? If not, you should post two different questions...

Comment: Thanks! I have separated them.